# Problem getting to big ring with XTR M960 Shift Lever

Tags: shimano, derailleur, shifter

First, I don't think it's a derailleur issue.  I already played around with the barrel adjuster at the shift lever, as well as the limit screws without success.  The derailleur appears to be properly aligned.

I also swapped the inner and outer cables to try to resolve the issue, with no success.

I have a 3 speed front XTR shift lever.  Small and middle rings work fine, but when trying to shift to the large ring, the lever won't click the way it does for the middle ring.  Seems like the lever needs to move a little more before it hits the point where it clicks.

When I remove the shift lever mechanism from the housing (cable loosened), I can get it to click, but when I put it back in the housing, it still won't click in the big ring position, whether there is tension in the cable or not.

Is there some way of adjusting the shift lever itself to control where it clicks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the right combination of Google foo to find what I was looking for.  This [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCRG8J35CVc) breaks it down that old grease in the shifter is keeping the teeth from catching.

By spraying WD-40 into the housing via the inner cable hole.  Let it soak a bit, and work it in via shifting up and down.  It may take a few minutes, as mine took 5-10 minutes and a couple of treatments but finally it started getting the big ring click.

After the WD-40 is dry, then lube the inside of the shifter with a regular lube to keep it operating well.

Comment: I'm glad you figured the answer to your problem.  Please accept your own answer by clicking the check mark, so that your answer doesn't percolate back to the home page eventually.  Cheers!

Comment: @rclocher3 Ty.  It won't let me do it yet, but I will.